# Is possible to compile and programme ATtiny10 with AVR CrossPack?

Tags: avr, programming, mac, attiny

For my next project, I would like to use ATtiny10, but I have computer only with Mac, so I cannot use AVR Studio. Can I use AVR CrossPack for programming this microcontroller?

I found this article about [programming ATtiny10](http://irq5.wordpress.com/2010/07/15/programming-the-attiny10/) (it is a year old text). The author is saying it is not possible to programm ATtiny with avr-gcc nor avr-as and avrdude cannot work with TPI.

So what (and how) can I use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The AVRA assembler can be used with the ATTiny4/5/9/10 MCUs and you can use an FTDI chip in bit-bang mode to program it.  I'm using a Mac myself and have taken this approach for now.  I'm not sure of the version of AVRA that comes in CrossPack is new enough and you will need to install a newer version of avrdude but it is possible.

I have a simple example on github [here](https://github.com/Wollw/ATTiny4-Example/).  It seems I might have patched my copy of AVRA for the 4, 5, and 9 but I believe the newest version supports the ATTiny10 on its own.  As for programming, that site you linked to is what I used to help me program them with an FTDI chip. You just need to add the programmer definition he has on his site to your avrdude.conf file and hook the it up to the pins mentioned in the description and it should work.

Comment: Thank you. I cannot find AVRA in CrossPack (I have latest version 20100115), so I will try to install it separately. Also, I have to install the newest version of avrdude, because in CrossPack is 5.8.